# Java Observer Problem

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

I am having some trouble with implementing my own observer in Java on the Android platform.

I have created a class call NetworkPathJni that uses an Observer interface class called NetworkPathJniObserver to notify other objects of changes.

Here is the code for NetworkPathJni.java

---

```
public class NetworkPathJni {

NetworkPathJniObserver networkPathJniObserver;

  public NetworkPathJni(NetworkPathJniObserver aObserver){

    networkPathJniObserver = aObserver;
    Log.d("Phone", "NetworkPathJni Created" );

  }

  public void NetworkPathStateChanged(int aAvailabilityState){
      Log.d("Phone", "NetworkPathStateChanged new state = " + aAvailabilityState );
      TAvailabilityState availabilityState = intToAvailability(aAvailabilityState);
      Log.d("Phone", "Is SipNetworkPath alive?" +  networkPathJniObserver.isAlive());
      networkPathJniObserver.NetworkPathStateChanged(availabilityState);
      Log.d("Phone", "NetworkPathStateChanged end" );
      Log.d("Phone", "Is SipNetworkPath alive? (2)" +  networkPathJniObserver.isAlive());

  }
```

---

And here is the code for the observer

---

```
public interface NetworkPathJniObserver {

void NetworkPathStateChanged(TAvailabilityState aAvailabilityState);

boolean isAlive();
}
```

---

The observer is implemented as follows in a class called SipNetworkPath

---

```
public class SipNetworkPath implements NetworkPathInterface, NetworkPathJniObserver{

NetworkPathObserverInterface observer;
NetworkPathJni networkPathJni;

public SipNetworkPath(NetworkPathObserverInterface aObserver){
    domainType = aDomainType;
    observer = aObserver;
    networkPathJni = new NetworkPathJni(this);
    Log.d("Phone", "SipNetworkPath created" );
}

//NetworkPathJniObserver

@Override
public void NetworkPathStateChanged(TAvailabilityState availabilityState) {
    Log.d("SipNetworkPath", "SipNetworkPath - Do networkpathstate changed!");
}

@Override
public boolean isAlive() {
    return true;

}
```

---

And SipNetworkPath is instanciated as follows

---

```
public class WifiNetworkPath extends SipNetworkPath{

public WifiNetworkPath(NetworkPathObserverInterface aObserver) {
    super(aObserver);
}
```

---

The logging shows that both NetworkPathJni and SipNetworkPath get created and that NetworkPathStateChanged(int aAvailabilityState) is called.

Within that method all the logging comes back but the method does not get called in the observer and I get false when I ask "Is SipNetworkPath alive?" in the logging.

Is the observer class losing reference or something or is there a mistake in my way of doing this?

Comment: this is pretty much code, cant you provide a smaller example? it would be easier if i could copy and paste in order to compile that junk of code. I cant see an error yet, but it should be very easy to find with help of my IDE. By the way, how should that EVER return false:public boolean isAlive() {return true;}

Comment: I'm not sure how simpler I can make it. It's not exactly a vast piece of code in my opinion. Thats exactly my question, why would it be returning false?? Is it something to do with the object losing reference or being collected by the garbage collector?

Comment: it would have been exactly your question if you had asked something like: "why does return true return false" and i would not have to search the whole code for errors - if return true doesnt return true something else than the program logic is broken. If you had tried to provide a SHORT example of this problem (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html), you would have found out that this likely has nothing to do with the observer pattern by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method `NetworkPathStateChanged` you're doing nothing with the availability state. Usually you would store it internally, like this:

```
private TAvailabilityState availablilityState = null; // or a more suiteable initial value
@Override
public void NetworkPathStateChanged(TAvailabilityState availabilityState) {
    this.availabilityState = availabilityState;
    Log.d("SipNetworkPath", "SipNetworkPath - Do networkpathstate changed!");
}
```

Then, in method `isAlive` you would respond based on the state:

```
@Override
public boolean isAlive() {
    return availabilityState == TAvailabilityState.ALIVE; // <-- this is just a guess, I don't know this class or enum.  
}
```

---

In this case (referring to your comment) another implementation of `NetworkPathJniObserver` must exist somewhere or you still have an old class file on the classpath. Just because: if an `isAlive()` method returns `false` while the one in the source code can't, then there **must** be some other code in your application.

I'd add some debug code to the method to clearly log *which* instances are actually called. (My guess would be, that the last compiled version(s) hasn't been deployed...)

Comment: Thanks for that Andreas but thats not the problem, the problem is that the NetworkPathStateChanged method never gets run when it is called. Same with the isAlive method, it doesn't seem to be run when its called as it should simply return true but it actually returns false.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, maybe you can tell us what was wrong.

Comment: Two instances of the Observer were being created which led to the second instance which had empty methods overriding the first instance.